# Is it possible to create a new PowerPoint presentation using office-js in the same window?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I use PowerPoint.createPresentation(base64) method in order to create a presentation.
But it is opened in a new window (new tab for web, new instance of PP for desktop). Is it possible to open a presentation in the same window?

Comment: maybe attribute target="_self" will help you…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Office JavaScript API doesn't provide any property or method for such tasks.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.